# c# + Inputbox + multidimensional array

Tags: c#, vb.net

Im having abit of trouble trying to figure out how to get my VB inputbox to work and then add the value entered into my multidimensional array.

The array looks like this:

```
int[,] toys = new int[5, 4];
```

and so far this is what i have for the inputbox.

```
 string value;
 int num;

 value = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.InputBox("Enter Number of Products", "Monday");
```

I need to have Monday-Friday values for 4 weeks.
To do this i was thinking of using the inputbox in a for loop perhaps? Everytime the user enters input for that day it would insert it into the array?

Then repeat that for the 4 weeks?

Open to any suggestions as i am not sure the best way to go about it.

Thanks!

Comment: begin by just not using inputboxes or messageboxes in your application. they are evil programming shortcuts that cripple the user experience.

Comment: I need to mention that its required that i use that type of inputbox, my main issue is moving the values into my multidimensional array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the inputbox isn't really the best way to accept inputs, as a matter of fact, it's not even good, but to satisfy your needs for now, this should be the shortest route.

VB.NET

```
 Dim toys(4, 3) As String
    For week As Integer = 0 To 3
        For day As Integer = 0 To 4
        toys(day, week) = InputBox("Please enter value for Day " & CStr(day + 1) & " in week " & CStr(week + 1) & ".")
    Next day
 Next week
```

C#

```
string[,] toys = new string[5, 4];
for (int week = 0; week <= 3; week++) {
    for (int day = 0; day <= 4; day++) {
        toys(day, week) = Interaction.InputBox("Please enter value for Day " + Convert.ToString(day + 1) + " in week " + Convert.ToString(week + 1) + ".");
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Chris, Thanks for the heads up. Im currently studying software development and im constantly being told the stuff im being told is the bad way of doing things. :(

Also its saying toys is a variable used like a method for the c# thing

Comment: @MirroA, happy to help. Yeah it's better to avoid reserved names such as that of what you said about toys. Don't worry, this is good practice even if you're using the 'bad' ways of programming it. You get to learn stuff and that is what matters. If my post answered your question, I'd appreciate it if you mark it as answered :) Thanks.

Comment: It did, I managed to get it all working. Now the real challenge is to format the output of the array :)~

Comment: @MirroA, Alright thanks :) Do what you can for now, if you can't do it after many tries, drop me a message here and post the question :)

Comment: i tried using foreach loop but can't seem to figure it out.. i basically need to be outputting it sort of like a grid. like this; http://imgur.com/c0ihHyI
just the week 1-4 and mon-fri style

Comment: hi Mirro , @chris_techno25 is not your personal consultant. this is a different question unrelated to the original. you need to try coding that, and if you really can't after all, you open another question with some code samples of your work so far, and chris or someone else will be glad to help.

Comment: @MirroA I suggest you give yourself another half an hour to figure it out. Push your limits. There were times when I had problems and I always hesitated to ask for help because because I wanted to do it myself, for 3 simple lines of codes it took me 3 days to get it. Not saying you should do the same, just saying you can do it :) If all else fails, open up another question and give the exact details you want. What kind of control would you like have the data displayed on? Is that a listview on the picture? Send me the link of the question you opened so I can help you :)

Comment: @chris_techno25, I have actually made some progress and im probably really close, i opened the other question just to see some replies regarding what i have done now. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21273723/c-sharp-output-multidimensional-array-to-grid-style-textbox