# output multidimensional array to grid style textbox

Tags: c#, arrays

I am having trouble with text formatting while trying to output my array into a textbox.

I'm required to output something like this; https://i.stack.imgur.com/sX6AI.jpg
sort of like a table minus the borders.

Ive managed to produce something similar, but i'm out of ideas.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/rvAUY.jpg

My code is:

```
string[,] toys = new string[5, 4];
for (int week = 0; week <= 3; week++)
{
    for (int day = 0; day <= 4; day++)
    {
        toys[day, week] = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.InputBox("Please enter value for Day " + Convert.ToString(day + 1) + " in week " + Convert.ToString(week + 1) + ".");
    }
}
txtOutput.Text += "Mon" + "\t" + "Tue" + "\t" + "Wed" + "\t" + "Thu" + "\t" + "Fri" + "\t" + "\r\n";
txtOutput.Text += "Week 1" + "\t" + "\r\n";
txtOutput.Text += "Week 2" + "\t" + "\r\n";
txtOutput.Text += "Week 3" + "\t" + "\r\n";
txtOutput.Text += "Week 4" + "\t" + "\r\n";

foreach (string text in toys)
{

    txtOutput.Text += text + "\t";
}
```

Comment: Is this Silverlight, or Web Forms? Neither one has a textbox that works like this.

Comment: It's not the only wrong  thing here but, why `"Mon" + "\t"` instead of  `"Mon \t"` ?

Comment: Oh i was taught to use the visual basic inputbox (for the current project im working on) so had to use that.
Also was unaware i could code it that way "Mon \t", seems alot easier!

Comment: You still haven't said what kind of project this is. Visual Basic doesn't have any "inputbox", BTW.

Comment: Oh its windows form & im coding in c#, sorry i forgot to mention that it was a windows form application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is by drawing line by line as follows:

```
//first, set up the toys index by accepting some inputs
string[,] toys = new string[5, 4];
for (int week = 0; week <= 3; week++)
{
    for (int day = 0; day <= 4; day++)
    {
        toys[day, week] = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.InputBox("Please enter value for Day " + Convert.ToString(day + 1) + " in week " + Convert.ToString(week + 1) + ".");
    }
}


//then, print the output line by line by looping through the toys array
//the first line must be separate because the headings are not part of the array
txtOutput.Text += "Mon" + "\t" + "Tue" + "\t" + "Wed" + "\t" + "Thu" + "\t" + "Fri" + "\t" + "\r\n";

for (int week = 0; week <= 3; week++)//foreach week
{
    //construct the line of text which represents the week's data
    txtOutput.Text += "\tWeek " + (week+1) + "\t";
    for (int day = 0; day <= 4; day++)
    {
       txtOutput.Text += toys[day,week];
       if(day != 4)
       {
         //so long as it is not the last day, then you have to tab over
         txtOutput.Text += "\t";
       }
    }

    //wrap things up by moving to the next line before you iterate to the next line
    txtOutput.Text += "\r\n";
 }
```

Comment: I like this approach. Seems logical. Although its saying this part is not working.
txtOutput.Text += toys[week, day];

Comment: Nevermind... I think I switched up your indexes on the toys array.  See the edited code above, which should have fixed the issue.

Comment: Oh i see what you mean, its still saying "Index was outside the bounds of the array." for the:  txtOutput.Text += toys[week,day];

Comment: that line of code should now read txtOutput.Text += toys[day,week];  it should not read txtOutput.Text += toys[week,day];

Comment: thanks for explaining it! Makes alot more sense now :)

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked into the StringBuilder Class?

Ref- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx

```
StringBuilder myName = new StringBuilder(); 
myName.appendFormat("Name = {0}, hours = {1:hh}", myName, DateTime.Now); //For example.
```

That should be a good place to start.

Answer (score 1):

just a little idea, 
you'd better init the titles(like "Mon", "Tue"..etc.. ) into the array, like this

```
string[,] toys = new string[,]
{
    {" ","Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri"},
    {"Week 1", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"},
    {"Week 2", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"},
    {"Week 3", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"},
    {"Week 4", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"}
};
```

and

```
toys[week + 1, day + 1] = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.InputBox(...
```

and when you output, use the **GetLenght()** cause toys[,] is a two-dimensional array.

```
for (int i = 0; i < toys.GetLength(0); i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < toys.GetLength(1); j++)
    {
        this.textBox1.Text += toys[i, j] + "\t";
    }
    this.textBox1.Text += "\r\n";
}
```

result
https://i.stack.imgur.com/LZu7u.jpg

Comment: This way seems like alot more code? For this part:
toys[week + 1, day + 1] = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.InputBox(...
Would i have to paste that like for each day of the week? or loop it?

Comment: toys[day + 1, week + 1] = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.InputBox("Please enter value for Day " + Convert.ToString(day + 1) + " in week " + Convert.ToString(week + 1) + ".");

Answer (score 0):

Check out my way of doing it. I just read your message so yeah... Maybe this will also help in the future... This is the shortest I could think of :)

```
TextBox1.Text = "\t" + "Mon" + "\t" + "Tues" + "\t" + "Weds" + "\t" + "Thurs" + "\t" + "Fri";
for (int week = 0; week <= 3; week++)
    {
    TextBox1.Text += Environment.NewLine + "Week " + Convert.ToString(week + 1) + "\t";
    for (int day = 0; day <= 4; day++)
        {
        TextBox1.Text += toys[day, week] + "\t";
        }
    }
```